# Microphone input's maximum float number is 1. How to make it bigger and change it from 1? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code that takes a microphone input(when pressing "T)" and returns it as a float number (one final float number). However, when I yell or blow into microphone the maximum float it prints is 1 and no matter how I yell or say quietly after it printed 1, it keeps printing 1 only. How to change it to a bigger number. Let's say if I yell it would return a bigger number than if I just say quietly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
public class MicInputs : MonoBehaviour
{
public enum micActivation
{
    HoldToSpeak,

}
public micActivation micControl;
private float sample_max = 0.0f;

public static float MicLoudFloat;
public List<float> recorded_values = new List<float>();
private string theMicroDevice;
AudioClip recordOfClips;
//microphone initialization
void MicroInitialization()
{
    if (theMicroDevice == null) theMicroDevice = Microphone.devices[0];
    recordOfClips = Microphone.Start(theMicroDevice, true, 999, 44100);
}

void StopMicrophone()
{
    Microphone.End(theMicroDevice);
    Maximum_Level(); // Collect the final sample
    MicLoudFloat = sample_max;
    print(MicLoudFloat);

}

void Awake()
{
    recordOfClips = AudioClip.Create("nameOfClip", 128, 2, 1000, true);
}
//AudioClip clip = myRecordedOrOwnClip;
//reate(string name, int lengthSamples, int channels, int frequency, 
bool stream,
//_sampleWindow = clip.samples;
//AudioClip _clipRecord = new AudioClip();
//AudioClip _clipRecord = AudioClip.Create("nameOfClip", 128, 2, 1, 
true);
int samplesWindows = 128;



//=========THIS IS THE START OF THE METHOD========


// get data from microphone into audioclip
float Maximum_Level()
{

    float[] waveData = new float[samplesWindows];
    int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null) - (samplesWindows 
+1); // null means the first microphone
    if (micPosition < 0) return 0;
    recordOfClips.GetData(waveData, micPosition);
    // Getting a peak on the last 128 samples
    for (int i = 0; i < samplesWindows; i++)
    {
        float wavePeak = waveData[i] * waveData[i];
        if (wavePeak > sample_max)
        {
            sample_max = wavePeak;
        }
    }
    return sample_max;
    //float maximum_level = 0;
    //float[] waveData = new float[samplesWindows];
    //int micPosition = Microphone.GetPosition(null) - (samplesWindows 
+ 1); // null means the first microphone
    //if (micPosition < 0) return 0;
    //recordOfClips.GetData(waveData, micPosition);
    //// Getting a peak on the last 128 samples
    //for (int i = 0; i < samplesWindows; i++)
    //{
    //    float wavePeak = waveData[i] * waveData[i];
    //    if (maximum_level < wavePeak)
    //    {
    //        maximum_level = wavePeak;
    //        recorded_values.Add(maximum_level);
    //    }
    //}

    //float max = recorded_values.Max();
    ////print(max);
    //return max;


    //print(maximum_level);
    //return maximum_level;
}

//=========THIS IS THE END OF THE METHOD========



void Update()
{
    if (micControl == micActivation.HoldToSpeak)
    {
        //if (Microphone.IsRecording(theMicroDevice) && 
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.T) == false)
            //StopMicrophone();
        //
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T)){ //Push to talk
            MicroInitialization();

        }
        //
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.T)){
            StopMicrophone();


        }

    }

    Maximum_Level();
    // levelMax equals to the highest normalized value power 2, a small 
number because < 1
    // pass the value to a static var so we can access it from anywhere


    //print(MicLoudFloat);
}

//bool isItInitialized;

//// start mic when scene starts
//void OnEnable()
//{
//    MicroInitialization();
//    isItInitialized = true;
//}

////stop mic when loading a new level or quit application
//void OnDisable()
//{
//    StopMicrophone();
//}

//void OnDestroy()
//{
//    StopMicrophone();
//}


// detects if the mic gets started & stopped when application gets 
focused
//void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
//{
//    if (focus)
//    {
//        //Debug.Log("Focus");

//        if (!isItInitialized)
//        {
//            //Debug.Log("Init Mic");
//            MicroInitialization();
//            isItInitialized = true;
//        }
//    }
//    if (!focus)
//    {
//        //Debug.Log("Pause");
//        StopMicrophone();
//        //Debug.Log("Stop Mic");
//        isItInitialized = false;

//    }
//}
}
```

Comment: The actuall sensor only returns values from 0 to 1. Either make the checks at partial numbers. Or just multiply the input by a number. Something like 100.

Comment: In StopMicrophone() I multiplied sample_max by 100. It simply give me the number just multiplied by 100. Which means instead of 1 it gives 100.

Comment: If the sensor returns 0 to 1 as  float, and you want "half of full volume", jsut compare it to be >= 0.5 You got float values. Use them.

Comment: Since you say that it *does* return a bigger number when you yell than when you talk quietly, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: If the problem is that your microphone has a small dynamic range, that's not a problem you can solve in software. Buy a better microphone.

Comment: @ Eric Lippert  It returns the biggest number which is 1, no matter how load I yell. But if I speak quietly it returns within a range 0-1. How to make it to return a value which is bigger than 1, for example 1.5 or 2.8 or any number depending how load I talk.

Comment: Multiply this result by 1.5 or 2.8. If it does not help, it means that you are trying to solve different problem than you describing.

Comment: That's what "dynamic range" means. If the microphone is returning a 1 that means that the volume is *louder than the loudest sound detectable by the microphone*.  Similarly, zero is *quieter than is detectable by the microphone*. If you need a microphone where the loudest sound it can detect is much louder, *that's a hardware problem*. You need to buy a microphone with a higher rated dynamic range.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sensor returns only a 0 or a 1, it's not 0->inf, if you want to something else, like checking how load is the voice from 0 to 100, you could record it and check the audio file highest bump and return that.